# Raspberry Pi has two ip addresses

Tags: networking, dns

when I enter nslookup in my macbooks terminal, the output is:

```
Server:     192.168.2.1
Address:    192.168.2.1#53

Name:   raspberrypi.fritz.box
Address: 192.168.2.32
Name:   raspberrypi.fritz.box
Address: 192.168.2.200
```

192.168.2.200 is the static ip I gave to my raspberry through the /etc/network/interfaces.

My etc/hosts file look like this

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       raspberrypi
```

Where does the 192.168.2.32 come from?

Comment: Was this either a WiFi address or more likely the DHCP address assigned before you set the static IP (and cached either by your macbook or local router) ?

Comment: @SteveRobillard Im not sure. currently my raspberry is connected using ethernet. before that, it was connected via wifi but with the same static ip. maybe before setting the static ip the .32 ip could be the raspberrys ip. is it possible to reset the cache? I already did sudo discoveryutil mdnsflushcache and sudo discoveryutil udnsflushcaches but that did not help

Comment: Are you having issues because of this? If the rPi is properly connected and reachable on the x.x.x.200 IP, you should be fine ... the other IP will probably clear in due time.

Comment: @goldilocks I think this question is not off-topic and related to Raspbian 2015-05-05 image. I am also stucked here, why DHCP is also assigning different IP even if I have defined one in /etc/network/interfaces. Please open this thread.

Comment: @AnandKumar Questions about basic network configuration belong on our larger sibling site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  I know there are a lot here already, but if you look through them, I think you will notice there is a low success rate at solving the problem.  While U&L is not always better, it often is with this stuff; there's simply a larger community with a greater depth of knowledge of all things linux.  It also makes more sense to *try* and keep all these kinds of questions in one place.

Comment: @goldilocks as Anand Kumar has said, this is a specific Raspbian error, described also here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=111887 it is a bug in the Raspbian package and will contradict all "basic network configuration" topics, since this is about resolvconf *not* honoring static IP adresses and *always* using the DHCP.

Answer (score 2):

what does `ip addr show eth0` give as output on the rPi? This is useful to determine where the problem lies:

1. Does your Pi have 2 IPs? (likely not based on what you showed from /etc/network/interfaces but worth checking)
2. Is your network router caching a DNS entry for your raspberrypi.fritz.box name? You can check this from the admin settings on the router user interface typically.
3. Is your Macbook caching the old entry? Flushing the DNS cache would help here - but it won't help if (as per 2. above) the router continues to broadcast 2 DNS entries.

Once you have isolated where the problem is (Pi, router, Mac), you can troubleshoot the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check /etc/network/interfaces to see if there is additional thing written.
It usually consists of loopback and eth0.